# Django debug display all variables of a page

Tags: django, variables, templates, debugging

Is there a template tag (or any other trick) I can use to display all the variables available in a page?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

If [DEBUG](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#debug) is enabled, there's a [template tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/) called [{% debug %}](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#debug)

Answer (score 94):

There are several options (some of them already listed before):

1. django builtin [debug tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#debug) - I use this boilerplate to display it properly:

> <pre>
> {% filter force_escape %}
> {% debug %}
> {% endfilter %}
> </pre>

2. [Django debug toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) - has a [template panel](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/panels.html#template) for this purpose
3. One can use [django template debug](https://github.com/calebsmith/django-template-debug) to display application's tags like attributes, variables and details or you can even set a breakpoint inside of a template where you can inspect everything with [pdb](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) debugger (or ipdb) **[EDIT 16.3.2024]: The project seems no longer maintained :( - latest commit is from 2017-11**

Usually all debug features work only when the app is in [DEBUG](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#debug) mode.

Comment: Dang. Both of the Urls for #3 lead to a 404. :(

Answer (score 20):

Pro tip. Use `textarea` and auto select `onclick` for easier copy-paste:

```
<textarea onclick="this.focus();this.select()" style="width: 100%;"> {% filter force_escape %} {% debug %} {% endfilter %}</textarea>
```

Answer (score 10):

The [debug toolbar](http://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar) does all this and much, much more. See the [screencast](http://vimeo.com/6640136) for more. If you literally just want the variables, you could try

```
assert False, locals()
```

in your view

Comment: Thnaks. As I'm using a generic view, is there a way to summon a "assert False, locals()"

Comment: guys, I've debug toolbar installed and working but it doesn't display all the variables available to me in the template... am i missing something.. where does this assert false, locals() go and what exactly does it do?

Comment: If you've written a custom view, just put it near the end of your view. If you're using a generic view, you'd need to wrap it in your own view. I think that would work, anyway.

Answer (score 8):

A slightly more complex solution with better rewards is to load [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) (documentation [here](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/))

There's an option called 'Templates' with another option to 'Toggle context' and you can see all the variables passed to your template, as well as the ability to see the code behind the template.

[image: Example of django-debug-toolbar template debugging]

Comment: I am getting `'<<triggers database query>>'` as the value

Comment: I would read the documentation and if that fails, I would go to the django-debug-toolbar project and request help: https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar

Answer (score 2):

If you use pycharm of professional version, you can set breakpoints on some lines in a template file and view the variable value.

For more detail, follow this link.https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-django-templates.html