# django dump out a variable

Tags: django

In Django can I dump out a variable to see what is in it within a view (not using command line)?

for example:

```
device = mobile(request)
    print device
    abort

or 
 device = mobile(request)
 return HttpResponse(device)
```

Comment: you probably want to take a look at [Django debug toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar)

Comment: I see, will install, sounds like just what I need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing to a file is usually a fool-proof way to "dump" data as a debug method when you are working with a hooked framework that doesn't otherwise lend itself well to direct debugging.

e.g.

```
device = mobile(request)
with open('path/to/debug_out.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(device)
abort
```

for convenience, you could put this in a predefined function in some debug helper module. Alternatively, you could use sys.excepthook to automatically write all exceptions to this file, before forwarding/re-raising them.

Comment: Too complicated for simple fast dump.

Comment: @PetrPeller You do realise that the entire point is that you put this in a function and call a simple `logfoo("blah")`. The point of writing to a file is that it is fool proof, always leaves a trace, and doesn't rely on hooking/listening and rendering the debug output. Simply asserting or throwing an exception is not the best way since you might have many points of control flow you want to introspect. Your comment and vote is completely nonconstructive, and I would of hoped that you could at least illustrate with a better alternative.

Answer (score 3):

There is a similar question:

[Django debug display all variables of a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213977/django-debug-display-all-variables-of-a-page)

You can type

```
assert False, locals()
```

in your view to see all your view variables. Or use the {%debug%} template tag inside your template which will do the same.