# Django: Is there a way to display a variable in a Django template like foo.inspect in Rails?

Tags: django, django-templates

Rails provides an awesome way to inspect variable contents in a template: `<%= foo.inspect %>`. Is that possible to do the same in Django? `{% debug %}` is a bit too messy.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213977/django-debug-display-all-variables-of-a-page) that has a number of good suggestions.  If {% debug %} is unappealing, then it might be easier to inspect the variables in the view prior to the template rendering the page with the variables in question.