# django what variables available in a template .html file?

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I'm trying to figure out what objects and variables are available within the template .html file

This is in the view file

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
Userx = get_user_model()

class ProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name ='profiles/user.html'

    def get_object(self):
        username = self.kwargs.get("username")
        if username is None:
            raise Http404
        return get_object_or_404(Userx,username__iexact=username, is_active=True)
```

In the user.html file

```
{% block content %}
username={{ user.username }}
{% endblock content %}
```

my questions
1. why is the name of the object in the user.html file called user?

2. how would one find documentation on the object names and fields of the user object?
3. how would one see all available variables accessible in a particular .html template"

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

1. This is the name defined to refer to the user object  (hard to expect something else)
2. Here you can find every fields of this [User object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User)
3. You can use `{% debug %}` to inspect the context and A LOT of other informations, and this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/) can help you to find a specific keyword to use in the templates.

   Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213977/django-debug-display-all-variables-of-a-page) too, especially for the following line (helpful to inspect the debug output) :

   ```
    {% filter force_escape %} {% debug %} {% endfilter %}
   ```